# How to tell if an X and Y coordinate are inside my button?

Tags: java, android

I have managed, with great difficulty, to make a bitmap overlay the screen. I can also get touch input, however it gets touch input for EVERYWHERE on the screen.

I want to know how I would be able to check if the touch was on my bitmap, which is visible on the screen.

The service and view class is below. I have thought and thought, but I couldn't think of a way to do it :(

```
package <package>;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    ButtonView mView;
    Bitmap bit;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.button);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Ingress Tools Running");
        builder.setContentText("Click to stop Ingress Tools");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(
                this, StopActivity.class), 0));
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(1, builder.build());

        mView = new ButtonView(this, bit);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (mView != null) {
            ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .removeView(mView);
            mView = null;
        }
    }
}

class ButtonView extends ViewGroup {
    private Paint mLoadPaint;
    private Rect r;
    private Bitmap bit;

    public ButtonView(Context context, Bitmap bit) {
        super(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "HUDView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mLoadPaint = new Paint();
        mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLoadPaint.setTextSize(10);
        mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        r = new Rect();
        r.set(380, 134, 468, 213);
        this.bit = bit;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bit, 100, 100, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int area = bit.getWidth() * bit.getHeight();


        //if (event.getY() <= maxY && event.getX() <= maxX) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Open tools: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        //}
        return true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider using `FrameLayout` (or any other subclass of `ViewGroup`) instead of `ViewGroup` directly. Because your current implementation of `onLayout` method is not correct, which will lead you to problems with displaying of child views.

Now, closer to your question. You should ininitialize `Rect` and just store left, top, right and bottom position of your `Bitmap`. As I can see, currently you're initialized `r` variable, but not using it anywhere.

So, you can initialize it like this:

```
r = new Rect(100, 100, 100 + bit.getWidth(), 100 + bit.getHeight());
```

Now in `onTouchEvent` you can just check:

```
r.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
```

Comment: Hmmmm, this works but now nothing else recieves the touch event. As in, I can't click anything else on the screen (although this may have happened before I added this).

Comment: @LiamW if you want your `MotionEvent` to be propagated further, then you should return false from `onTouchEvent`

Comment: I do return false outside the if statement, but nothing happens if I touch outside the image.

Comment: @LiamW this is probably because your view (and your window) is `FILL_PARENT`

Answer (score 22):

this works for any view

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (inViewInBounds(myButtonView, (int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
                    // User moved outside bounds
                    Log.e("dispatchTouchEvent", "you touched inside button");
                } else {
                    Log.e("dispatchTouchEvent", "you touched outside button");
                }

        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

 Rect outRect = new Rect();
    int[] location = new int[2];


 private boolean inViewInBounds(View view, int x, int y) {
        view.getDrawingRect(outRect);
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);
        return outRect.contains(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: works but I dont understand the functions. Why should I call View::getLocationOnScreen after calling View::getDrawingRect? Shouldnt Rect also have the x y positions? Also I guess Rect::offset() repositions the rect but I dont really understand it.

Answer (score 16):

```
Rect rect = new Rect(); 
getHitRect(rect);
if (rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {}
```

you can use getHitRect(Rect). it returns the Hit rectangle in parent's coordinates. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHitRect%28android.graphics.Rect%29) the documentation

Comment: Normally, this answer is the way to go. Although, he draws `Bitmap` instead of `View`, so `getHitRect` can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use if statement with method `if(r.contains(x, y))` on that button which you want to check. This method will return true, when x and y point is inside rectangle r. You can also make public method within that class, so you can access it outside ButtonView class with button object reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
// We assume MotionEvent is from the direct View parent so we are in the same co-ordindate space
fun View.isWithinBounds(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val rect = Rect(x.roundToInt(), y.roundToInt(), (x + width).roundToInt(), (y + height).roundToInt())
    return rect.contains(event.x.roundToInt(), event.y.roundToInt())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the "touch event" happens, it's going through all view's tree.
F.e. if you have Linear layout and ImageView on it and user touchs the screen on ImageView, then touch event intercepts and firstly it'll be handled at LinearLayour and then at the ImageView.

If you want to block event f.e. on the bitmap, then you should override onTouchEvent for Bitmap and return true value. This will mean that you handled this event and it won't be available for LinearLayout.

```
image.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return true;  // attentively read documentation for onTouc interface
            }
        });
```