# In android Is there any way to identify touch happened on a button or checking buttons available in the screen

Tags: android

I am trying to capture user touch events(for now basically I am focusing only the button clicks) from the screen. Following are the 2 approach I followed.

**Approach 1:** Using overlay screen on top of activity.

To capture touch event, I have overrided onTouch method of OnTouchListener interface. Through MotionEvent I get X,Y coordinates but I didn't get to know that the touch happend on a button. And always the touch was returning of action ACTION_OUTSIDE. I got stuck there to identify the touch happend on a button.

**Approach 2:** Directly working on touch events on activity.

To capture the touch event I have overrided dispatchTouchEvent method of Activity class. Whenever there is a touch on the screen, for 1 touch 3 events are captured(ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP). I refered this link ([How to tell if an X and Y coordinate are inside my button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931816/how-to-tell-if-an-x-and-y-coordinate-are-inside-my-button)) and made use of 3rd answer from it to know the touch happend on a button. I made use of 2 views for the example shared.

**Following is the code for the same.**

```
Rect outRect = new Rect();
int[] location = new int[2];

1. private View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxact_copy_popupmenu, null); // empty screen
2. myView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

   Log.d(TAG, "Dispatch-touch me");

   if (event.isButtonPressed(MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "****BUTTON PRESSED****");
    }

   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (inViewInBounds(myView, (int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
            Log.e("dispatchTouchEvent", "you touched inside button");
        } else {
            Log.e("dispatchTouchEvent", "you touched outside button");
        }

   }

   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

}

private boolean inViewInBounds(View view, int x, int y) {

   view.getDrawingRect(outRect);
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    outRect.offset(location[0], location[1]);

   return outRect.contains(x, y);

}
```

When 1st myView is used in the code, even though we press on a button (and also outside the button) it returns us saying it's not pressed on a button. If 2nd myView is used and press anywhere(on button and also outside the button) on the screen it says pressed on button.

So I am stuck here how to proceed further. Please help me in ho to identify the touch happened on a button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can just listen for touch events on a button by:

```
myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: @Shruthi `I'm trying to capture the events from SDK not directly from the app`- I don't quite understand this. Can you please explain in more detail like what  you are trying to actually achieve? I think you misunderstood the concept of capturing touch events of views, and hence trying to complicate a simple thing.

Comment: I am trying to capture click events whenever user clicks on a button in an application throughout all the screen. I have already built application **ABC** And I have an another project **XYZ** converted as library. Same is imported in my ABC project. I have my own activity in XYZ and dispatchTouchEvent is overrided there. Whenever there is a touch on a screen, I want to understand whether the touch happened on a button through this method. Or is there any other way we can capture touch events or click events??

Comment: @Shruthi AFAIK that is **not possible**. You can also assume the problems/security issues that will arise if that is possible in any way.

Comment: Is there any other approach to get the solution?? Thankyou