# How to figure out the view has a button in a place where the touch happened

Tags: android

I have an application and with the application I want to have the same log happens in multiple activities. If I want to write a helper class which will notify when the button is pressed, what should I be doing? And that notififcation will tell enough so that I don’t have to code what the button is how to access the button. If the button is there we should be getting. Even if I am writing in an activity itself, without knowing what the view is, can I know the view has a button and if the button was pressed?

I have an activity, in that activity there’s a view which dynamically gets generated. The view may or may not have buttons. If there are 2 activities, one activity has a button other doesn’t but I still want to write a generic code to be notified when the button in the view is pressed. And to do that I have overriden the touchEvent and I get the touch event but I am not able to reach out to the view to see there is a button in a view where the touch happend. What is the way to figure out the x and y coordinates on a touch event to verify if there is button or not. I also know that we can go ahead and put the log in a onClick (simpler solution), but I am avoiding it.

Comment: *If* I understood correctly - you can make a single `CommonButton` view class and use that to dynamically add buttons to your layouts. Now, within this `CommonButton` view class you can pass you click event

Comment: Your question is not very clear, maybe you should write with a example like ActivityA, ActivityB something like that. From what I was able to understand, I will try answering your question you can do `findViewById(R.id.my_button)` and if the button exist in the parent, you will receive the view, which can then be used to set listener, if the button doesn't exist it will return null.

Comment: Our intention is not to make button view has generic. Instead, we want to know the touch happened on a button or no.

Comment: Please go through this for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830389/in-android-is-there-any-way-to-identify-touch-happened-on-a-button-or-checking-b#comment82624449_47830549