# How to handle an action when a user removes a finger from a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, button, ontouchlistener

I need to handle the action when the user pulls a finger off the button by clicking on it, but does not release it. I tried to use OnTouchListener, but, as I understood it, it only processes the movement of a finger or the release of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's existing the `OnTouchListener` also:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
           Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
           if (!r.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
               // your action
           return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: As I understand it, this action is triggered when the user touches the button, and I need an action, when he pressed the button and goes out of the border with his finger, without releasing it

Comment: Do you mean drag the button ?

Comment: I need a certain action on the screen at this moment

Comment: See the updated answer, this event is called when you drag on the button.

Comment: but it is also called when the finger moves along the surface of the button, without going beyond its borders

Comment: then I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931816/how-to-tell-if-an-x-and-y-coordinate-are-inside-my-button

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


            Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


            Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");



            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.d(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:

            Log.d(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

may this code help you.

Comment: OnTouchEvent is not called because the touch event has already been intercepted by the button

Comment: did you use onclick event also??

Comment: yes, but I can do everythihg in ACTION_DOWN. Another problem is that I use button selector

Comment: you cannot use both at same time if you use onclick event OnTouchEvent never work.